# Правильный вывод материалов из базы данных

Tags: php, json

Из базы нужно вывести товары, у которых по 3-4 фотографий в карточке товара.

Выглядит это так:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87aHO.jpg]

Таких товаров по-умолчанию загружается сразу 12 - А это сразу 36 фотографий.

Как лучше реализовать вывод, чтобы максимально быстро материалы загружались?

ибо при прокрутке страницы, еще по 3 материала добавляется.

Мне от вас нужен совет по быстрому выводу товаров. Мне нужно максимально быстро их выводить.

Comment: Применять старые-добрые методы оптимизации загрузки изображений. Например, ленивую загрузку: грузить изображения только если они в вьюпорте. А вывод из БД тут вообще ни при чём - выгрузить 36 ссылок на фото и проставить их в `data`-атрибуты не так уж сложно.

Comment: @Maqsood по второй части вопроса — Создайте дополнительный вопрос и опишите как у Вас хранятся данные и как фильтрацию Вы собираетесь делать. По 2 вопроса в одном задавать не стоит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых необходимо изображения обрезать до нужного размера что бы лишнего не грузить.

Есть 2 варианта быстрее отдать страницу в Вашем случае (если Вы переживаете за изображения):

- Использовать ленивую подгрузку — изначально создаётся блок в котором указана ссылка на изображение, но нет его самого. На блок вешается background, который показывает что изображение заружается, и после полной отрисовки страницы начинаем загружать изображения в блоки
- Загружаем сначала первые изображения и указываем в js ссылки на остальные и после полной отрисовки страницы начинаем загружать остальные изображения.

Comment: Я реализую оба варианта, очень интересно посмотреть результат. Спасибо Вам!